# csv.writer and every value separated by a comma, column separated by "," - what am I missing?

Tags: python, csv, networkx

I wrote a simple program to import a CSV edgelist, calculate the metrics, then I want to write the metrics for each node to a CSV file.  Calculating the metrics is easy, but correctly writing the CSV is where I'm having trouble.  With the way that I'm doing it now, the CSV results ends up having every value separated by a comma, and columns separated by "," - example below where the first column is the node id and other columns are results for that node id:

7,6,1,8,5,9,",", ,0,.,1,0,2,4,5,9,",", ,0,.,0,0,0,0,4,5,",", ,0,.,5,0,8,9,4,7,",", ,0,.,0,0,8,8,3,1

4,6,9,7,7,3,",", ,0,.,1,4,3,4,4,3,",", ,0,.,0,0,0,0,9,0,",", ,0,.,5,2,7,2,4,2,",", ,0,.,0,1,1,2,9,1

**Code**

```
import sys
import networkx as nx
import csv


# load CSV edgelist into NetworkX
G = nx.read_edgelist(sys.argv[1], delimiter=',')


# calculate centrality metrics
degree = nx.degree_centrality(G)
between = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
close = nx.closeness_centrality(G)
eigen = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G)


# write centrality results to a list
centrality = []
for i in G:
  centrality.append("%s, %f, %f, %f, %f"%(i, degree[i], between[i], close[i], eigen[i]))

# write list to CSV
outfile = sys.argv[1].replace('.csv', 'metrics.csv') 
with open(outfile, 'wb') as f:
  csv.writer(f).writerows(centrality)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`writerows` expect a list of lists of values, where each "outer" list is a row of values.

You are, however, passing a list of strings. `writerows` just iterates over each string's elements, so each letter becomes its own column. Commas need to be quoted when they are csv values, so they are added as `","`.

Drop the string formatting (the `csv` module handles that) just say:

```
centrality.append((i, degree[i], between[i], close[i], eigen[i]))
```

The inner parentheses denote a [tuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#tuple) notation. You could say more clearly:

```
row = i, degree[i], between[i], close[i], eigen[i]
centrality.append(row)
```